# Is there a way to recreate lost SSTable index and other component files?

Tags: recovery, cassandra

In Cassandra, in addition to the main sstable file, which ends with big-Data.db, there appear to be 7 other  files, namely:

- big-CompressionInfo.db
- big-Digest.crc32
- big-TOC.txt
- big-Summary.db
- big-Index.db
- big-Filter.db
- big-Statistics.db

I'm not sure how important the files are, but while moving files, I lost all files except the `big-data.db` file.

Is there any way I can recreate those files and make the sstable usable? I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Primary index component is missing for sstable /home/cassandra/data/gps/module-4792fbc0b82111ed9bb69bcebdf415e4/nb-171026-big
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:467)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:381)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$2.run(SSTableReader.java:551)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask$1.call(FutureTask.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.call(FutureTask.java:47)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:57)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can read the data file without the index file and the compressionInfo file. The built in tooling will definitely not open it and return an exception as you have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra SSTables are made of [several components stored in separate files](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/Component.java):

- `*-Data.db` - contains actual data
- `*-Index.db` - stores index of partition keys and their position in the data file
- `*-Filter.db` - stores serialised bloom filter for row keys in the data file
- `*-CompressionInfo.db` - holds metadata about uncompressed length, chunk offsets, etc
- `*-Statistics.db` - holds statistical metadata about the data in the SSTable
- `*-Digest.crc32` - holds the checksum of the data file
- `*-Summary.db` - stores a summary of the partition index, sampling every N keys
- `*-TOC.txt` - table of contents, lists all components for the SSTable
- `*-SI_.*.db` - holds [secondary index](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/cql/indexes.html) on a column(s) if defined on a table

The [minimum components required to read a data file](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/SSTableReader.java#L459-L532) are:

- the partition index file (`*-Index.db`) - partition offsets are necessary since columns (and their sizes) are not fixed
- the statistics file - contains the serialisation header necessary to deserialise the SSTable contents
- compression info file - required if compression is enabled
- table of contents - verification of compression info file depends on existence of TOC

It isn't possible to recreate these component files if they are missing.

As a workaround, remove the files which have missing components then repair the affected table. Cheers!